# Stopping on row command c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to make script way to continue for few seconds?
I mean program would run, then stop on some row, wait there for few sec and then jump on next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit trickier in C# than JavaScript, because you have to declare a coroutine.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Example());
    }

    IEnumerator Example()
    {     
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }
}
```

in JS it's just

```
yield WaitForSeconds(5);
```